# what is work area in system programming?

Tags: systems-programming

i have read it when i was learning linking. When the program is going to be executed it was first linked by linker. At that time it was put in work area. Now i want to now what is this work area?

Comment: Parth, can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Static linking is done as part of the compilation process today.

Compile->Assemble->Link = Executable.

Typically when a program is loaded today on the desktop, it is placed into virtual memory and any dynamic linking is performed then.

Comment: Are you sure that's what a work area is?  I just assumed that's where the compiler puts its output.

Comment: I'm *assuming* he means the area in memory and he's asking about the changes in linking over time; link techniques in the 60s/70s versus now. I'm not completely certain, though. You might be correct.